# Literally can't install ubuntu on my laptop :(((((((

Tags: system-installation

I've installed Ubuntu twice on virtualbox successfully and after messing around with it for a while I wanted to install it on my old xp netbook to give it new life and also cuz Linux is kinda cool! The problem is that no matter what I try I cannot get it to install!

NOTES: It's a 32 bit machine running on BIOS and it's hard drive has windows xp (im not planning on dualbooting but idk if wiping it first will help much)

First I just flashed the latest iso (20.04) on a flash drive with rufus, all it gave me was a grub menu at the start, when I press start ubuntu it just did the black screen with blinking underscore, and the test ram gave me
`error symbol grub_efi_secure_boot not found`

nomodenset also didn't work

Eventually I realized that this is a 32 bit machine and that I used a 64 bit so I got the first 32 bit image that popped up during search (https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/). This got me a bit further, as I can now get to the "keyboard equals happy person in bubble" screen. It gets me to the splash loading screen with the 5 dots but then just stays there forever. Again, neither nomodeset nor using the "happy person in bubble menu" (im sorry i rly don't know what to call it hhhh) options will get me past the loading screen.

Any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Ubuntu is way too much for that machine. Try lunbuntu. https://lubuntu.net/

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on CMD as a administrator
**bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi** ( it worked on Windows 10 i hope i t could work on your XP )

this enables grub bootloader and also Ubuntu is too much for the machine to handle friend, as David suggested try lubuntu it is much lighter.